# aggregating multiple values at once

Tags: scala, apache-spark

So I'm running into a speed issue where I have a dataset that needs to be aggregated multiple times.

Initially my team had set up three accumulators and were running a single foreach loop over the data. Something along the lines of

```
val accum1:Accumulable[a]
val accum2: Accumulable[b]
val accum3: Accumulable[c]

data.foreach{
        u => 
                accum1+=u
                accum2 += u
                accum3 += u 
}
```

I am trying to switch these accumulations into an aggregation so that I can get a speed boost and have access to accumulators for debugging. I am currently trying to figure out a way to aggregate these three types at once, since running 3 separate aggregations is significantly slower. Does anyone have any thoughts as to how I can do this? Perhaps aggregating agnostically then pattern matching to split into two RDDs?

Thank you

Comment: Do you want to execute and arbitrary set of aggregations at once?

Comment: @zero323 no it's 3 specific aggregations. It's just that one of them has a different type than the others.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell all you need here is `aggregate` with `zeroValue`, `seqOp` and `combOp` corresponding to the operations which are performed by your accumulators.

```
val zeroValue: (A, B, C) = ??? // (accum1.zero, accum2.zero, accum3.zero)

def seqOp(r: (A, B, C), t: T): (A, B, C) = r match {
  case (a, b, c) =>  {
     // Apply operations equivalent to
     // accum1.addAccumulator(a, t)
     // accum2.addAccumulator(c, t))
     // accum3.addAccumulator(c, t)
     // and return the first argument
     // r
  }
}

def combOp(r1: (A, B, C), r2: (A, B, C)): (A, B, C) = (r1, r2) match {

  case ((a1, b1, c1), (a2, b2, c2)) => {
     // Apply operations equivalent to
     // acc1.addInPlace(a1, a2)
     // acc2.addInPlace(b1, b2)
     // acc3.addInPlace(c1, c2)
     // and return the first argument
     // r1
  }
}

val rdd: RDD[T] = ???

val accums: (A, B, C) = rdd.aggregate(zeroValue)(seqOp, combOp)
```

Comment: Hi zero323. So unfortunately when I attempted to try this method out I ran into some REALLY nasty garbage collection issues that I hadn't seen when I was doing each value individually. Is it possible that by creating tuples I'm running into a serious GC issue since Scala is treating each tuple as a new object? Each value is of type mutable.Map

Comment: If your return new tuple then each one is a new object. I mean it will still reference the same maps but tuple itself is not the same. You should return mutated argument. `combOp` is applied once per partition so it shouldn't matter although you can do the same thing.

Comment: In general `aggregate` (or map side aggregations in general) can be heavy on GC (see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-772) although I don't think there is another issue than returning new tuples here.

Comment: ohhh ok. So if I were to modify the original tuple and then make sure I return that original tuple then I won't run into as much of an object creation issue? Also, would you say that aggregates have larger GC issues than accumulators?

Comment: Well, you cannot modify tuple but you can modify mutable objects inside. As far as I can tell it should solve the problem but I haven't seen your code or metrics so it is just a guess. Regarding the second question - if implemented right there is no good reason to for it to be. From the other hand I don't use Accumulators for anything else than simple diagnostics so maybe I've missed some performance gains.

Comment: Everything I've read thusfar seems pretty unanimous that accumulators should not be used this way, which is why I was surprised at the initial outcome.